# How can I ignore Python 3 syntax when running script under Python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-unittest

Is it possible to ignore or mask out pieces of Python 3 syntax when running script under Python 2?

I'm trying to write a unittest to run against a Python module under Python 2 or Python 3.

The test includes syntax that is only valid under Python 3 ("yield from") - and I only want to run those tests when I'm running the test on Python 3. Is there a method to disable or mask out this Python 3 code when I run it under Python 2 so that I don't get a syntax error being thrown when I run the unittest module?

See cut-down example below:

```
import unittest
try:
    import asyncio
    # We must be running under Python 3 - run the sync and async tests.
    ASYNC_SUPPORTED = True
except ImportError:
    # We must be running under Python 2 - only run the sync tests.
    ASYNC_SUPPORTED = False

class TestSyncMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        # Test for synchronous functionality here
        pass

# Test for asynchronous functionality here
class TestAsyncMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    @unittest.skipIf(not ASYNC_SUPPORTED, "Async not supported")
    def test_async_1(self):
        @asyncio.coroutine
        def go():
            yield from sc.identify_a(1, 0x2B, True, True)
```

If I attempt to run this unittest under Python 2.x I get a syntax error at the "yield from" instruction, because "yield from" is not supported under Python 2.x. Ideally, I'd like to prevent the whole of the TestAsyncMethods class from being parsed if the unittest is being run under Python 2.x. Does anyone know a way to do it?

Comment: You could split it out into another file and conditionally `import` it.

Comment: Anything short of a SyntaxError you in theory can do if six.PY3, else kind of syntax. However, using the `__future__` module greatly reduces the need to do so.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The conditional import should be part of the library configuration, i.e. it should change the import paths.

Comment: Thanks all. It sounds like conditional imports are the way to go, but, in this case, I'm wondering how this is going to affect test discovery with something like nose. I guess I'll have to suck it and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
from sys import version_info

if version_info[0] > 2:
    ASYNC_SUPPORTED = True
    import asyncio
else:
    ASYNC_SUPPORTED = True
    asyncio = None
```

As Alexander pointed out you will still need to split out in py2 and py3 modules. Unless you are going to get creative with exec, which I would highly recommend to avoid at almost all cost.

Comment: This doesn't fix the "yield from" syntax, which produces a SynaxError in Python2. The whole file itself cannot be imported, which is why doing conditional imports is almost necessary here.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Conditional imports as shown above are definitely the solution. Unfortunately I haven't found a way to prevent the unit test discovery tools (nose or py.test) from finding and attempting to parse/run the Python3 module when running under Python2 (but that's a separate issue).

Answer (score 2):

A good way to achieve this is to exclude modules based on their name, to avoid trying to import them.

This is a convention I'm currently using: all tests that are python2 and python3 compatible have a "_py2_py3" suffix, all modules that are only python3 compatible have a "_py3" suffix, all modules that are only python2 compatible have a "_py2" suffix and so on.

To run all tests:

```
python -m unittest discover -s project_directory -p "test*.py"
```

To run python2 tests:

```
python -m unittest discover -s project_directory -p "test*_py2*.py"
```

To run python3 tests:

```
python -m unittest discover -s project_directory -p "test*_py3*.py"
```

You can create a test runner if you want:

```
# test_runner.py

import unittest

import six

if six.PY2:
    PATTERN = 'test*_py2*.py'
else:
    PATTERN = 'test*_py3*.py'


def start():
    unittest.main(
        module=None,
        argv=[
            'my_app', 'discover',
            '-s', 'tests',
            '-p', PATTERN])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```